# Can you change font size of println?

Tags: java, printing, fonts

Tried a little googling and everyone seemed to be wondering this for a lot more complicated projects:- is there anyway to make a `println` or `print` or `printf` that will be a bigger font size than normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

printf doesn't print with a font. It writes plain text (ascii, utf-8...) to a file. This file happens to be the terminal, but plain files have no concept of font.